# Does AlamofireObjectMapper / ObjectMapper support struct type mapping

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, alamofire, objectmapper

I am using [AlamofireObjectMapper](https://github.com/tristanhimmelman/AlamofireObjectMapper) to parse json response to my object. The AlamofireObjectMapper is a extension of [ObjectMapper](https://github.com/Hearst-DD/ObjectMapper/).

According to their documents, my model class has to conform to `Mappable` protocol. For example:

```
class Forecast: Mappable {
    var day: String?
    var temperature: Int?
    var conditions: String?

    required init?(_ map: Map){

    }

    func mapping(map: Map) {
        day <- map["day"]
        temperature <- map["temperature"]
        conditions <- map["conditions"]
    }
}
```

In order to conform to Mappable protocl, my model class has to implement the required initializer and the mapping function for each field. It makes sense.

**BUT, how does it support `struct` type?** For example, I have a `Coordinate` structure, I try to conform to the `Mappable` protocol:

```
struct Coordinate: Mappable {
    var xPos: Int
    var yPos: Int

    // ERROR: 'required' initializer in non-class type
    required init?(_ map: Map) {}

    func mapping(map: Map) {
        xPos <- map["xPos"]
        yPos <- map["yPos"]
    }
}
```

I cannot make my `Coordinate` conform to the Mappable, because of the error I show above.

(I think it is quite often that using `struct` for coordinate data instead of using `class`)

**My questions**:

**Q1.** Does AlamofireObjectMapper or ObjectMapper library support `struct` type? How to use them parsing json response to a `struct` type object then?

**Q2.** If those libraries doesn't support parsing json response to struct type object. What is the way to do so in iOS with Swift2 ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

BaseMappable protocol is defined like this so you should declare each method to conform `Mappable`.

```swift
/// BaseMappable should not be implemented directly. Mappable or StaticMappable should be used instead
public protocol BaseMappable {
    /// This function is where all variable mappings should occur. It is executed by Mapper during the mapping (serialization and deserialization) process.
    mutating func mapping(map: Map)
}
```

Mappable protocol is defined like this

```swift
public protocol Mappable: BaseMappable {
    /// This function can be used to validate JSON prior to mapping. Return nil to cancel mapping at this point
    init?(map: Map)
}
```

You have to implement it accordingly:

```
struct Coordinate: Mappable {
    var xPos: Int?
    var yPos: Int?
    
    init?(_ map: Map) {
    }

    mutating func mapping(map: Map) {
        xPos <- map["xPos"]
        yPos <- map["yPos"]
    }
}
```

or

```
struct Coordinate: Mappable {
    var xPos: Int
    var yPos: Int
    
    init?(_ map: Map) {
    }

    mutating func mapping(map: Map) {
        xPos <- map["xPos"] ?? 0
        yPos <- map["yPos"] ?? 0
    }
}
```

Constructor ***cannot be marked as required*** because struct cannot be inherited. mapping function has to be mark as mutating because mutates stored data in structure...